# What does this notation for a vector subspace mean?

Tags: vector-spaces

The notation in question: $$U_1 = \mathbb{R}(3, 1)$$

In case the task that this is extracted from is necessary:

"Check if this subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$ forms a vector subspace."

I`m not quiet understanding what the $\mathbb{R}$ in front of the vector means in this context, so I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me out here real quick.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it is the set
$$U_1 = \big\{t\cdot(3,1)\mid t\in\mathbb{R}\big\}. $$

Comment: It denotes the set of scalar coefficients here. In other words, $\mathbf R(3,1)=\{\lambda(3,1)\mid\lambda\in\mathbf R\}$.

Comment: @Bernard Alright thanks, that sound logical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never seen this notation before. But from the context it must be

$$\mathbb{R}(3,1)=\{x(3,1):x\in\mathbb{R}\}=\{(3x,x):x\in\mathbb{R}\}.$$